# anyone can tell me how to compare the var

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i want to compare this two value on grid view but when i using .text it will occur error?

[image]

the client side code look like this

```
<asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblremainqty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qtycart") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Error" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text=''></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this

```
int.Parse(Qty.Text) > int.Parse(RemainQty.Text)
```

or if it is not int value use float or decimal Parse etc. I hope it will help.

PS
`Qty.ToString()` will return you name of type Label.

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' to type 'System.IConvertible'. why will show this error msg wht mean

Comment: Are you sure that you use Property Text of object type of Label?

Comment: What is full name type of Label?

Comment: It impossible to get this error with code that I added here. Because Parse method accept only string value, so if you try to pass not string you will get compile error. Make sure that you use int.Parse(Qty.Text) > int.Parse(RemainQty.Text)

Comment: after i clean and build it ok @@

Answer (score 0):

> Operator >(Greater than) is only used to compare Integer Value Not
>   String Value. If still you need to use that operation Then you can
>   convert into Int and Use that operation

Comment: ok thx but when i convert it show this msg 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: if (Convert.ToInt32(Qty.Text) > Convert.ToInt32(RemainQty.Text))

Comment: Try to use Convert.ToInt32 or Int.Parse

Answer (score 0):

the client side code look like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblremainqty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qtycart") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Error" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text=''></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
Convert.ToInt32(Qty.Text) > Convert.ToInt32(RemainQty.Text)
```